# how to use Java to log in through a redirect to SAML

Tags: java, redirect, saml

Due to the sensitivity of the product, I cannot give you specifics other than it is a SAML request to login.

Ok I have a site [www.main.com](http://www.main.com)
When I open this in a chrome/firefox browser it redirects to
[www.main.com/authredirect.it?pram_url=https%3A%2F%2Fauthorizingsite.com&SAMLRequest&sjouierngongvoznvuznvozsrgolzrgnbv&RelayTohhttps%3A%2F%2Fmain.com](http://www.main.com/authredirect.it?pram_url=https%3A%2F%2Fauthorizingsite.com&SAMLRequest&sjouierngongvoznvuznvozsrgolzrgnbv&RelayTohhttps%3A%2F%2Fmain.com)

Now the URL switches to the authorizingsite.com and asks for creds.

Once I log in it takes me back to [www.main.com](http://www.main.com) and I can progress as needed.

**how on earth am I supposed to work two redirects a login and a last redirect?**

I need to automate a part of the page and download the excel sheet but WOW just sorting the login has been a headache.

Is anyone able to help with this? I am at my wits end.

Comment: I voted to close this question because there is no example code. Please [edit] your post to include a [minimal, complete, readable, and reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: So please post the code that you've tried for doing it and tell us what error is or problems you're facing with it please

Comment: Question is too generic. I recommend to study how SAML works (what is SAML request/ SAML response, diferent AML bindings, ...) and then you will know how on earth you are supposed to work with SAML.

Comment: from your code, redirect to the IdP's SSO endpoint with a SAMLRequest parameter. In your code wait for the response at your Attribute Consumer Service (ACS) URL. That's where the SAMLResponse is sent by the IdP, via browser redirect. Parse and validate  the SAMLResponse then decide whether the user represented in the AttributeStatement is valid.